# Can't extract data transaction from blockchain by using nodejs TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')

Tags: javascript, node.js

I try to get data from https://public-api.solscan.io/transaction/last?limit=10 but got error

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')
    at parseTransactionData (C:\Users\User\NodeSolana\main.js:8:18)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

that's code

```
const axios = require("axios");

async function parseTransactionData() {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get("https://public-api.solscan.io/transaction/last?limit=10%22);
    const transactions = response.data.result;

    transactions.forEach((transaction) => {
      console.log(Transaction Hash: ${transaction.transactionHash});
      console.log(Block Number: ${transaction.blockNumber});
      console.log(From Address: ${transaction.fromAddress});
      console.log(To Address: ${transaction.toAddress});
      console.log(Value: ${transaction.value} ETH);
      console.log("-------------------------------");
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

parseTransactionData();
```

Comment: What is unclear about an error message such as _“Cannot read property `forEach` of `undefined`”_? You can’t read properties of `undefined`, but that’s what happens at `transactions.forEach` because `transactions` is `undefined`; it’s trying to get `forEach` off of `undefined` — not possible. If you don’t know why `transactions` is `undefined`, use the debugger or look at intermediate values that led to the result `transactions`: `console.log(response.data, response)`. What makes you think you need to read the `result` property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the **response.data.result** is undefined. So, it undefined in transactions variable and you cannot use forEach loop on undefined array/object. That's why it is throwing error **Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')**

To check what you are getting from url, you can console the response or **response.data** before accessing **response.data.result**. To do this, add below line before **const transactions = response.data.result;**

> console.log(response.data)